# How are AMF3 string tables built?

Tags: string, flex3

I am working on AMF3 format decoding. I have used inline objects and variables, however I am having problem with the String reference. Can anyone tell how String reference table is built?

Currently, I have:

```
    var object:Object = new Object();
    object.s1 = "abc";
    object.s2 = object.s1;
    object.s0 = "111";
    byteBuffer.writeObject(object);
```

then I write this to a `byteBuffer` and finally to a file. I am wondering how String references are built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex builds a table for string references. As soon as Flex encounters a string in an object, it does the following:

- If the string is new:

  - Add the string to the table and increase the reference number.
- Otherwise

  - add a reference to the string.